# Switching sim card (iPhone X)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, network, esim

My son lost his phone, unfortunately, so I am going to order his new one next week. My question is: if I allow him to put a new sim card in my phone what will happen if someone tries to call me on my regular number?

He will have a different number on his sim card so I'm not sure if people will be able to leave a voicemail. Will it just keep ringing or what, if anyone knows, will happen until his comes? Thanks, I'm trying to be a nice and very understanding parent.

Comment: Better not mix your data with your son's data. Perhaps you have an old iPhone lying around? –

Comment: Just FYI, this is a general cell phone question and not an Apple or iPhone-specific question.